# Android x86 native resolution fails

Tags: images, macos, android-x86, virtualization

Running [Android x86 iso](http://www.android-x86.org/download) (5.1 rc1 or 4.4 r5) in my native resolution 2880x1800 fails with black screen with blinking cursor. Actually it is a prompt accepting commands but stops without any message or anything on screen.

Last commands visible on screen were: 
[image: last commands]

I ran it with vga=ask parameter:

```
/kernel initrd=/initrd.img root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=android_x86 nomodeset vga=ask SRC= DATA=
```

And chose the offered 2880x1800x32: 357
[image: offered resolutions]

Same if I run it with parameters directly in a command line either the vga= or UVESA_MODE=2880x1800 or tried UVESA_MODE=2880x1800x24 or UVESA_MODE=2880x1800x16.

If I choose 2560x1600x16, it works well, except for the resolution is low.

I run it in Parallels Desktop on OS X.

How to run it in a native 2880x1800 resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue running Android-x86 on VMware (Windows host). The solution was to force the virtual machine to load enough memory for the virtual graphics adapter upon boot.

In my case, I had to place `svga.minVRAMSize = 536870912` manually in the vm settings file. For Parallels, I believe you should open up the VM's configuration, then in the *Hardware* section, under the *Video* group, change the *Video Memory* value.

The value is generally given in bytes, so 536870912 bytes = 512 MB. The rule of thumb to calculate how much graphics memory you need is to [multiply display values](https://superuser.com/a/256947/358758) (HRes x VRes x colors). So for a 2880x1800x32 resolution, you actually need `2880 x 1800 x 4` = `20736000 bytes` which is a little under 20MB. You'd be wise, though, to set up more than that - like I did - to account for 3D graphics, [multiple buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) and [compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing), and other fancy GPU tricks inherent to Android (See [Graphics architecture](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html) and [Android Graphics Internals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4579573/3258851)).

**[Contribution from OP]:** I tested and found that 64MB is the minimum amount of graphics memory necessary to run Android 6 at 2880x1800x32 resolution on the Retina MacBook Pro 15".