# How to resize Android screen in VirtualBox with UEFI?

Tags: android-x86, screen-resolution, virtualization

I have 64-bit Android 7.1.2, obtained from [android-x86_64-7.1-rc1.iso](http://www.android-x86.org/download). I installed it on VirtualBox (latest version, 5.1.2.8) with UEFI mode. (The host is 64-bit Linux Lubuntu 16.04.)

The installation all works fine apart from the fact that the screen is fixed at 1024×768. The various sizes given in the VirtualBox menu > View > Virtual Screen 1, which range from 640×480 to 1920×1200, are all greyed out.

I would like to be able to resize the Android screen, making it both smaller and larger, and even full-screen if possible. Sadly, the usual method, Guest Additions, isn't supported on Android.

I've tried following various instructions. The vast majority seem to be valid only for non-UEFI installations, although I tried them anyway. The only [one for UEFI that I found](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/180196/32823) doesn't work for me.

The methods that I have found include:

- Issue the command:
  `vboxmanage setextradata Android CustomVideoMode1 1152x864x32`
  (this obviously would work only for that one resolution).
- Adding various commands to Grub, either at boot or permanently in `EFI/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

  - `set gfxpayload=keep`
  - `set gfxpayload=1152x864x32`
  - `vga=ask`
  - `vga=834`

I am at a total loss how to proceed. Can you help, please?

Answer (score 1):

The following steps should resolve the issue, although I can't test on VirtualBox.

### Temporarily:

1. Upon booting the virtual machine, press <kbd>F10</kbd> once the boot screen appears
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot command
3. Navigate to the end of the last line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert indentation, and type in:

   ```
   set gfxpayload=1440x900
   ```

The resulting boot command should now be:

```
setparams 'Android-x86 2017-12-16'

    search --set-root --file /android-2017-12-16/kernel
    linux /android-2017-12-16/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.s\
elinux=permissive buildvariant=userdebug
    initrd /android-2017-12-16/initrd.img
    set gfxpayload=1440x900
```

Of course, the actual kernel date and time, as well as the resolution you want to set, should differ.

Press either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, or <kbd>F10</kbd>, to boot.

Note that there is no need for the trailing `x32` in the resolution value. But from my testing, it should work with it as well.

### Permanently:

(needs root)

1. From the Terminal Emulator, type in `su` to gain administrative privileges
2. run the following commands:

   ```
   mkdir /mnt/boot
   mount /dev/block/vda1 /mnt/boot
   vi /mnt/boot/boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```
3. from the `Vi` editor, press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter Insert mode
4. navigate to the end of the last line before the `}` symbol from the first section (should be line #7)
5. press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and do **Step 4** from the "*Temporary*" part of my answer
6. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit Insert mode
7. Type in `:wq` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit Vi
8. Back in the terminal emulator, execute:

   ```
   umount /mnt/boot
   ```

   optionally, also execute `rmdir /mnt/boot`.

It's done.

---

Let me know what problems you were having, exactly, if possible. There is a chance that your virtual machine does not have enough Graphics Memory to support the resolution you want. Check this answer, also from me: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/160371/57668.

Comment: Marc, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I had already given up and reinstalled without UEFI. However, I had at the time already tried with the `gxfpayload` without success (there was something similar that I also tried, though I forget now what it was). It seemed that VirtualBox simply didn't support Android well. I read elsewhere that I should try a different package such as VMWare, but I wasn't going to learn a new package. Anyway, thank you for your effort and answer.

Comment: @PaddyLandau You're welcome, man. If I can also make a suggestion: in the future, consider giving [virt-manager](https://virt-manager.org/) a try. It's a tool developed by RedHat and distributed freely, that makes creating, managing and using virtual machines very straightforward. I find it much simpler than VirtualBox, in all fairness.

Comment: With android 7.1,virt-manager and kvm-qemu with uefi..doesn't work,start only at 1024x768