# How do I get Android-x86 (32-bit or 64-bit) non-UEFI to boot in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

**EDIT**: I'm getting similar results in both 32-bit and 64-bit.

## Summary

I am installing [Android-x86 version 7.1 32-bit or 64-bit](http://www.android-x86.org/download) in VirtualBox.

If I install it using UEFI (64-bit only), it works, but [I cannot resize the screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/183789/32823), a problem to which I have been unable to find an answer.

Therefore, I need to install it without UEFI, so that I can resize the screen.

## Problem

The Android installation runs smoothly. But, no matter what I have tried, once installed, the non-UEFI Android system won't boot.

If I use a GPT hard disk, I get this error message when booting the newly-installed Android, whether 32-bit or 64-bit:

```
FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.
```

If I use an MBR hard disk, I get this error message when booting the newly-installed Android 64-bit:

```
  Trusted GRUB now booting command list

  Progress:
Error 15: File not found

tGRUB: ******************************************
tGRUB: * An error occured which might result in *
tGRUB: * an unverifiable or insecure system     *
tGRUB: * state. !!! BOOTING WILL BE STOPPED !!! *
tGRUB: ******************************************
```

And the 32-bit starts with 100% CPU and goes nowhere (very fast!).

## More information

### Host

- Linux Ubuntu version 16.04 64-bit
- VirtualBox version 5.1.28

### Guest

- Type Linux, Version "Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x" (32-bit or 64-bit as appropriate)
- System Base Memory 2,048 Mb
- System EFI turned off
- Storage

  - Controller: IDE for the optical drive to hold the Android-86 ISO
  - Controller: SATA for a 40 Gb hard disk

## Question

How can I get Android-x86 to boot on a non-UEFI system on VirtualBox, please?

Comment: Use Marshmellow as it is the stable build for x86 project. 
P.S. you should try [Anbox](https://anbox.io/)

Comment: Thank you for the ideas, @DeepakGangwar. Unfortunately, 6.0 gives the same error on startup. Anbox looks interesting, but I think that it needs much more work — it doesn't even start on my system (though it installs fine), and anyway it doesn't come with Google Play Store.

Comment: Updating Grub also fails. Miserably.

Answer (score -1):

When you try to install Android x86 on pc HDD, try to provide a boot partition through Create/modify partition and make it bootable. Followed by that create a new partition as Linux. write both the partition and after that install the android x86 on the linux partition (formatting as ext4).

It will work, after allocating a bootable partition. I tried and it worked.

Comment: The question of Paddy Landau was to install Android x86 in a virtual environment of VirtualBox. As your answer only covers installation on a physical pc it does not answer the question of Paddy Landau.